# python selenium get images links in div

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i want to get all the images in a div into text but i couldnt find a solution. i have tried several methods but i fail. does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<div class="goods_descr_images">
     <a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" href="//www.xxx.com/preview/1202090/p1_4058391_c58ad212.jpg"></a>
     <a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" href="//www.xxx.com/preview/1202090/p1_4058391_0c39e11a.jpg"></a>
     <a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" href="//www.xxx.com/preview/1202090/p1_4058391_5ae0a383.jpg"></a>
     <a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" href="//www.xxx.com/preview/1202090/p1_4058391_99d6b754.jpg"></a>  
     <a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" href="//www.xxx.com/preview/1202090/p1_4058391_5ae0a383.jpg"></a>
     <a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" href="//www.xxx.com/preview/1202090/p1_4058391_99d6b754.jpg"></a>
     <a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" href="//www.xxx.com/preview/1202090/p1_4058391_5ae0a383.jpg"></a>
     <a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" href="//www.xxx.com/preview/1202090/p1_4058391_99d6b754.jpg"></a></div>
```

if anyone writes a correct code,
i can see where i went wrong.
icant access the links in the href area

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
goods_descr_images_div = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "goods_descr_images")
a_tags = goods_descr_images_div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
links = [url.get_attribute('href') for url in a_tags]
```

Comment: a_tags = goods_descr_images_div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
thank u your comment but doesnt works. error

Comment: Which line? it's not possible the error was for line 3 (if there is nothing, the result will be an empty list). If the error is for line 2, run this code after loading page: print(driver.page_source), and see, Is there any difference between this and what you see in browser inspect?

Comment: Copy the result of print(driver.page_source) in a text manger and search can you find the "goods_descr_images" in it.